# Access 2003 text import wizard error

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

In Access 2003 I am trying to import a comma delimited text file using the import wizard. When I get to the field options window, the "Field Name:" control says Field1 and Field1 is highlighted in the bottom of the window. When I highlight Field2 in the bottom of the window, the "Field Name:" control still says Field1. It doesn't change to Field2. It doesn't matter what field I highlight in the bottom, the "Field Name:" control still says and stays on Field1. This is happening on some pc's but not others.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Everything I've checked has been the same; Windows version, Office version, Access version, same service pack (SP3) and all are 32bit. It's very strange....  seems the only thing that fixes the issue is a 'rebuild' of the pc.

Comment: Are you sure that you have MS Access 2003? Please check. I saw this2 years ago in MS Access 2002. It may was property of this version. In 2003 I've checked - it's OK.

Comment: yes, I am positive everyone has Access 2003 w/sp3